# A little guidance setting up FTP server authentication on Windows Server 2008 R2 standard?

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, authentication, ftp

I have a (clean) server running Windows Server 2008 R2 standard. I would just like to use it for serving a website and a FTP server through IIS. IIS is installed and serves my website propery. I have now added a FTP site but when I try to logon using my user/pass i get the following error:

> 530 User cannot login

From this article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200475) I understand that these four causes can be pointed out:

1. The Allow only anonymous connections security setting has been turned on in the Microsoft Management Console (MMC). **Not the case**
2. The username does not have the Log on locally permission in User Manager. **The user is in the `Users` group, however I'm not able to logon through RDP. I tried configuring this by following [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957044%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) article through `GPMC` however this only works when I'm logged in as a domain user on a domain controller which I'm not: I'm logged in as `administrator`**
3. The username does not have the Access this computer from the network permission in User Manager. **Not sure what this implies...?**
4. The Domain Name was not specified together with the username (in the form of DOMAIN\username). **Tried adding the server name: `server\username`, not working...**

I am an absolute server noob and I'd just like to be able to connect through FTP... **Any guidance is highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go into the FTP settings in IIS and change it from Anonymous to Authenticated. Then you need to give the user NTFS permissions to the folder(s) that you want them to have access to via FTP. Access control in IIS FTP server is controlled with NTFS ACLs.